# Transformer rated power in Powersystem

Tags: transformer

I am designing  a power system and I have to use a stepdown trafo to change the voltage from 380 kV to 110 kV.  I want to know  what is the rated power in the trafo 'Sn'. How can I know that ?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate power?

Comment: If "Powersystem" is a brand or product name then the capital 'P' is correct. If not it should be "power system". What is 'Sn'? Are we missing a diagram?

Comment: "KV" = kelvin-volt. "kV" = kilovolt. Fixed.

Comment: thanks for the editting , i mean with the 'Sn' the rated power of the trafo it is connected to a 50 km line and then to a Load with apparent power 80kVA and the realpart is 64 W

Comment: @MrRed this isn't a forum so add those facts to your question so that people answering don't have to scroll through the comments.

Comment: If you're designing a 380kV system, you probably shouldn't be asking basic questions here.

Comment: i am not designing in real life  , i am a student

Comment: Students asking questions here are expected to follow the rules of the site. See the comment by @Andy aka above. Another rule is that you need to ask your question in a way that demonstrates effort to solve the problem. Your question will be closed if not revised to follow the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Sn is the nominal apparent power. It is given by the nominal voltage Vn multiplied by the nominal current In. That would be multiplied by the square root of 3 for a three-phase transformer. You have Vn for the primary and secondary. The transformer rating plate or purchase specifications would state Sn, Vn, In and other parameters that state the operating conditions for which Vn, Sn and In are valid. There may be more than one  value stated for Sn etc. for different operating conditions.